# How to tag a row based on another column

Tags: r, tags

I have created another column, and in the new column - I would like the categories of high, low and medium based on zipcodes.

I have the list of zipcodes that are considered 'high', 'medium', and 'low' in a csv file.

I am able to do it individually, but with over 200 zipcodes, it becomes more difficult

---

This is what I've done for Individually:

```
#created new column
clinics$rate <- NA

#zipcode 97006 is considered low based on summary data
clinics$rate[clinics$zipcode==97006] <- 'low'
```

---

what can I do to tag it without entering it individually (over 200 zip codes)?

Comment: `clinics$rate[clinics$zipcode %in% lowzipcodes] <- 'low'` ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have two dataframes, one with zipcodes and your original info (say `df1`), and another with zipcodes and low, medium or high (say `df2`), you coudl join them like this; `library(dplyr)` then `final_df <- left_join(df1, df2)`, assuming zipcode had the same heading in both.  To make the categories straight in `df1`, you could look at `case_when()`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Say that your summary table of the zipcodes and ratings is called `zips`, then the following code should do the trick

```
clinics$rate <- zips$rate[matchclinics$zipcode, zips$zipcode]
```

What we're doing is using `match()` to index the `zips$rate` to output the ratings in the same order and number as the `clinics` dataframe